# Are these codes different?

Tags: c++, optimization, coding-style

I find when I research programming every book has a different way of doing the basics.

So I was wondering if these two codes are different or if they compile down to the same thing and what would be the benefit of one over the other.

```
if(a > b && b >c)
{}

if(a > b)
{
    if(b > c)
    {} 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have the same effect (the program will do exactly the same) and they'll likely cause the same machine code to be emitted.

The first one is shorter, the second one might be more convenient to step over in the debugger (debuggers step over code line by line).

Comment: Debuggers do _not_ necessarily step over code line by line, e.g. I can perfectly step into multiple method invocations in C++. That is even kind of annoying sometimes. Also, C# debuggers routinely break lines of code up according to their actual sequencepoints. I do imagine C/C++ debuggers exist that have the same feature (at least with respect to complete statements)

Comment: @sehe: Yes, you can *step into*, but usually not *step over*.

Comment: @Skeith: reread the answer or go to http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/, http://english.stackexchange.com/, or start 'existential doubt' at area51 :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the second example creates an extra branch.

Comment: Do you think short-circuit evaluation works without branches?

Comment: What do you mean extra branch?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a > b && b >c)
{}

if(a > b)
{
    if(b > c)
    {} 
}
```

They are same ....

Answer (score 0):

They're technically the same. However, the second style is clearer if you have a corresponding "else" statement. Most importantly, different groups have different code style conventions and you might want to follow to the specific one your team are using.

```
if(a > b && b >c)
{}
else if(a > b)
{}

if(a > b)
{
    if(b > c)
    {}
    else
    {}
}
```